# Create class for datatables to change color on table

Tags: javascript, datatables

How to create class that when Button clicked, this Row will change color.

```
var table1 = $('#futwidgetsql').DataTable({
  "bLengthChange": false,
  "sDom": 'tp',
  "bPaginate": false,
  "columnDefs": [{
    "targets": 13,
    "data": null,
    "className": "getthecase",
    "defaultContent": "<a href='#'><button>get this</button></a>"
  }]
});
```

Comment: This question currently shows no effort. If you have a specific problem, please edit your question to reflect that. This is not exactly a datatables question, but basic javascript event handling (though there are datatables apis which will assist depending on which version you're using)

Comment: I start with JavaScript i have think maybe I will found start what can I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr').click(function () {

        if(this.style.background == "" || this.style.background =="white") {
            $(this).css('background', '#A2D9CE');
        }
        else {
            $(this).css('background', 'white');
        }
    });
});
```